# Can't get edittext to work inside scrollview

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am trying to set up a page where I can put information into a database but there is too much to fit on one page. I have put it into a `scrollView` to deal with this but the `editText` is now not working, it won't show hints or allow me to put information in to it.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".informationActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/bottle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Write here"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/priceTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Price" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/priceEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="...."
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/goesWithTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="What does it go best with?" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/goesWithEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="...."
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/whereTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Where did you get it?" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/whereEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="...."
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I am not sure how to approach it without `scrollView` but nothing else seems to be working. Is there another format I could use to correct it or is it the xml that is the issue?

Comment: I think you have to give edittext width as match_parent/wrap_content Its's working

Comment: as I said in my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58711079/8405296), it's probably your editText width, but can be more stuff, for further question and problems, feel free to re-post in your question or raise another question.

Comment: So simple! Thank you!

Comment: why did you accept+unAccepted my answer?

Comment: it was an accident, I did accept it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change You Edittext layout width 0 to match_parent or wrap_content

Check Your Code Now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bottle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Write here"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/priceTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Price" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/priceEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="...."
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/goesWithTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="What does it go best with?" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/goesWithEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="...."
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/whereTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Where did you get it?" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/whereEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="...."
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your Position of EditText. Is it at the Bottom of the Layout. ALso Set Width to match_parent instead of 0 dp

Answer (score 0):

**Because your EditText width is 0.**

Replace below line

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

With

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```